# Entity Framework 4: Any way to know the plural form of an Entity Type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Given this code:

```
private ObjectQuery<E> GetEntity()
{   // Pluralization concern.  Table and Type need to be consistently named.
    // TODO: Don't get cute with database table names.  XXX and XXXs for pluralization
    return _dc.CreateQuery<E>("[" + typeof(E).Name + "s]");
}
```

Is there any way to determine an Entity type's plural name so I can access the table, rather than just adding an 's' to the name?

For example, Medium is singular and Media is plural.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the PluralizationService provided by EF 4. Here is a blog post that covers the service in good detail.

http://web.archive.org/web/20130521044050/http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/19/entity-framework-40-pluralization

Comment: @Miles, thanks. I updated the link with a link to the waybackmachine snapshot of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how entity framework does this, but I use the pluralizer from Ruby on Rails. You can find this at http://dev.rubyonrails.org/browser/trunk/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb#L106. This is easy enough to implement in C#.

The entire source for a translation to C# is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class Inflector
{
    private static List<KeyValuePair<Regex, string>> _pluralRules = new List<KeyValuePair<Regex, string>>();
    private static List<KeyValuePair<Regex, string>> _singularRules = new List<KeyValuePair<Regex, string>>();
    private static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _irregulars = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    private static List<string> _uncountables = new List<string>();

    static Inflector()
    {
        _uncountables.Add("equipment");
        _uncountables.Add("information");
        _uncountables.Add("rice");
        _uncountables.Add("money");
        _uncountables.Add("species");
        _uncountables.Add("series");
        _uncountables.Add("fish");
        _uncountables.Add("sheep");

        AddPlural("$", "s", true);
        AddPlural("s$", "s");
        AddPlural("(ax|test)is$", "$1es");
        AddPlural("(octop|vir)us$", "$1i");
        AddPlural("(alias|status)$", "$1es");
        AddPlural("(bu)s$", "$1ses");
        AddPlural("(buffal|tomat)o$", "$1oes");
        AddPlural("([ti])um$", "$1a");
        AddPlural("sis$", "ses");
        AddPlural("(?:([^f])fe|([lr])f)$", "$1$2ves");
        AddPlural("(hive)$", "$1s");
        AddPlural("([^aeiouy]|qu)y$", "$1ies");
        AddPlural("(x|ch|ss|sh)$", "$1es");
        AddPlural("(matr|vert|ind)(?:ix|ex)$", "$1ices");
        AddPlural("([m|l])ouse$", "$1ice");
        AddPlural("^(ox)$", "$1en");
        AddPlural("(quiz)$", "$1zes");

        AddSingular("s$", "");
        AddSingular("(n)ews$", "$1ews");
        AddSingular("([ti])a$", "$1um");
        AddSingular("((a)naly|(b)a|(d)iagno|(p)arenthe|(p)rogno|(s)ynop|(t)he)ses$", "$1$2sis");
        AddSingular("(^analy)ses$", "$1sis");
        AddSingular("([^f])ves$", "$1fe");
        AddSingular("(hive)s$", "$1");
        AddSingular("(tive)s$", "$1");
        AddSingular("([lr])ves$", "$1f");
        AddSingular("([^aeiouy]|qu)ies$", "$1y");
        AddSingular("(s)eries$", "$1eries");
        AddSingular("(m)ovies$", "$1ovie");
        AddSingular("(x|ch|ss|sh)es$", "$1");
        AddSingular("([m|l])ice$", "$1ouse");
        AddSingular("(bus)es$", "$1");
        AddSingular("(o)es$", "$1");
        AddSingular("(shoe)s$", "$1");
        AddSingular("(cris|ax|test)es$", "$1is");
        AddSingular("(octop|vir)i$", "$1us");
        AddSingular("(alias|status)es$", "$1");
        AddSingular("^(ox)en", "$1");
        AddSingular("(vert|ind)ices$", "$1ex");
        AddSingular("(matr)ices$", "$1ix");
        AddSingular("(quiz)zes$", "$1");

        AddIrregular("person", "people");
        AddIrregular("man", "men");
        AddIrregular("child", "children");
        AddIrregular("sex", "sexes");
        AddIrregular("move", "moves");
        AddIrregular("cow", "kine");
    }

    private static void AddIrregular(string singular, string plural)
    {
        AddPlural(singular.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + singular.Substring(1) + "$", plural.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + plural.Substring(1));
        AddPlural(singular.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + singular.Substring(1) + "$", plural.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + plural.Substring(1));
        AddSingular(plural.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + plural.Substring(1) + "$", singular.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + singular.Substring(1));
        AddSingular(plural.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + plural.Substring(1) + "$", singular.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + singular.Substring(1));
    }

    private static void AddPlural(string expression, string replacement)
    {
        AddPlural(expression, replacement, false);
    }

    private static void AddPlural(string expression, string replacement, bool caseSensitive)
    {
        var re = caseSensitive ? new Regex(expression) : new Regex(expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        _pluralRules.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<Regex, string>(re, replacement));
    }

    private static void AddSingular(string expression, string replacement)
    {
        AddSingular(expression, replacement, false);
    }

    private static void AddSingular(string expression, string replacement, bool caseSensitive)
    {
        var re = caseSensitive ? new Regex(expression) : new Regex(expression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        _singularRules.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<Regex, string>(re, replacement));
    }

    public static string Pluralize(string value)
    {
        if (_uncountables.Contains(value))
            return value;

        foreach (var rule in _pluralRules)
        {
            if (rule.Key.Match(value).Success)
            {
                return rule.Key.Replace(value, rule.Value);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static string Singularize(string value)
    {
        if (_uncountables.Contains(value))
            return value;

        foreach (var rule in _singularRules)
        {
            if (rule.Key.Match(value).Success)
            {
                return rule.Key.Replace(value, rule.Value);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    public static string Camelize(string value, bool firstLetterUppercase = true)
    {
        if (firstLetterUppercase)
        {
            return
                Regex.Replace(
                    Regex.Replace(value, "/(.?)", p => "::" + p.Groups[1].Value.ToUpperInvariant()),
                    "(?:^|_)(.)", p => p.Groups[1].Value.ToUpperInvariant()
                );
        }
        else
        {
            return
                value.Substring(0, 1).ToLowerInvariant() +
                Camelize(value.Substring(1));
        }
    }

    public static string Underscore(string value)
    {
        value = value.Replace("::", "/");
        value = Regex.Replace(value, "([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])", p => p.Groups[1].Value + "_" + p.Groups[2].Value);
        value = Regex.Replace(value, "([a-z\\d])([A-Z])", p => p.Groups[1].Value + "_" + p.Groups[2].Value);
        value = value.Replace("-", "_");

        return value.ToLowerInvariant();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
YourEntityObject.EntityKey.EntitySetName
```

Assuming your table names are plural.

If the generic method you have takes an entity (that inherits from `EntityObject`), then you can access the `EntityKey` from it.

```
private ObjectQuery<E> GetEntity()
{   // Pluralization concern.  Table and Type need to be consistently named.
    // TODO: Don't get cute with database table names.  XXX and XXXs for pluralization
    return _dc.CreateQuery<E>("[" + e.EntityKey.EntitySetName + "]");
}
```

Comment: Nice answer!  It has me thinking overtime of all the uses.  Since EF requires .OrderBy() before .Skip().Take(), could you extract the Key to put here -> .OrderBy( e.EntityKey.EntitySetName)?

Comment: You could, but you're querying a single type of entity (`e`), so everything will have the same `EntitySetName`.

Comment: e or E doesn't resolve to anything in the parenthesis.  typeof(E) has many things but I cannot see anything to do with EntityKey.  Where would this be?